# Commandbutton page selection

Tags: excel, vba, userform

So I have a commandbutton on a excel sheet and when I click on it brings up the userform But the page isn't starting from "Page1" rather its the page I was last using in the userform developer window. Therefore is there a way once clicked into the commandbutton the userform load up the first page everytime?

At the moment the commandbutton contains this (Userform is named as "WizardProp":

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  WizardProp.Show
End Sub
```

and the Openform contains this:

```
Sub openform()
WizardProp.Show
WizardProp.tbClient.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visible page number of a `MultiPage` object is defined by its `Value` (starting with 0).

Is "tbClient" the `MultiPage` object on your userform? Then place this code in your userform's initialization:

```
Private Sub WizardProp_Initialize()
    WizardProp.tbClient.Value = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Would `Unload Me` solve your problem? insert on the close of the userform. The Only issue is that it would rest the userform, data and all.

Comment: I already have "Unload Me" at the closing of the userform, but that doesn't really affect which page gets initialized first